# Vectorizing a function returning tuple using `numba` `guvectorize`

Tags: python, vectorization, numba

I am trying to vectorize a simple function which returns a tuple using `guvectorize`. Apparently, `numba` documentation does not contain any working exmple of `guvectorize` where the function returns `tuple`.

Initially, I was trying to do:

```
z = (x+y, x-y)
```

then I changed it to the following according to a stackoverflow answer.

```
z[:] = (x+y, x-y)
```

Still I get the errors which appear to be quite difficult to decipher for me. What I want is to vectorize a function which accepts multiple arrays of samdimension and returns an array of tuples having same dimension as the input arrays. For example, assuming the sample function if the input arrays are:

```
a = array([[4, 7, 9],
           [7, 1, 2]])
b = array([[5, 6, 6],
           [2, 5, 6]])
```

then the output should be:

```
c = array([[ (9, -1), (13, 1), (15, 3)],
           [ (9, 5),  (6, -4),  (8, -4)]], dtype=object)
```

My sample code and errors are given below:

```
from numba import void, float64, UniTuple, guvectorize
@guvectorize(['void(float64[:], float64[:], UniTuple(float64[:], 2))'], '(n), (n) -> (n)') 
def fun(x, y, z): 
    z[:] = (x+y, x-y)
```

```
<ipython-input-24-6920fb0e2a76>:2: NumbaWarning: 
Compilation is falling back to object mode WITHOUT looplifting enabled because Function "fun" failed type inference due to: Invalid use of Function(<built-in function setitem>) with argument(s) of type(s): (tuple(array(float64, 1d, A) x 2), slice<a:b>, tuple(array(float64, 1d, C) x 2))
 * parameterized
In definition 0:
    All templates rejected with literals.
In definition 1:
    All templates rejected without literals.
In definition 2:
    All templates rejected with literals.
In definition 3:
    All templates rejected without literals.
In definition 4:
    All templates rejected with literals.
In definition 5:
    All templates rejected without literals.
In definition 6:
    All templates rejected with literals.
In definition 7:
    All templates rejected without literals.
In definition 8:
    All templates rejected with literals.
In definition 9:
    All templates rejected without literals.
This error is usually caused by passing an argument of a type that is unsupported by the named function.
[1] During: typing of staticsetitem at <ipython-input-24-6920fb0e2a76> (4)

File "<ipython-input-24-6920fb0e2a76>", line 4:
def fun(x, y, z):
    z[:] = (x+y, x-y)
    ^

  @nb.guvectorize(['void(float64[:], float64[:], UniTuple(float64[:], 2))'], '(n), (n) -> (n)')
/home/user/.conda/envs/Py3DevLocal/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/compiler.py:742: NumbaWarning: Function "fun" was compiled in object mode without forceobj=True.

File "<ipython-input-24-6920fb0e2a76>", line 3:
@nb.guvectorize(['void(float64[:], float64[:], UniTuple(float64[:], 2))'], '(n), (n) -> (n)')
def fun(x, y, z):
^

  self.func_ir.loc))
/home/user/.conda/envs/Py3DevLocal/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/compiler.py:751: NumbaDeprecationWarning: 
Fall-back from the nopython compilation path to the object mode compilation path has been detected, this is deprecated behaviour.

For more information visit http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/deprecation.html#deprecation-of-object-mode-fall-back-behaviour-when-using-jit

File "<ipython-input-24-6920fb0e2a76>", line 3:
@nb.guvectorize(['void(float64[:], float64[:], UniTuple(float64[:], 2))'], '(n), (n) -> (n)')
def fun(x, y, z):
^

  warnings.warn(errors.NumbaDeprecationWarning(msg, self.func_ir.loc))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-6920fb0e2a76> in <module>
      1 from numba.types import UniTuple
----> 2 @nb.guvectorize(['void(float64[:], float64[:], UniTuple(float64[:], 2))'], '(n), (n) -> (n)')
      3 def fun(x, y, z):
      4     z[:] = (x+y, x-y)

~/.conda/envs/Py3DevLocal/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/npyufunc/decorators.py in wrap(func)
    178         for fty in ftylist:
    179             guvec.add(fty)
--> 180         return guvec.build_ufunc()
    181 
    182     return wrap

~/.conda/envs/Py3DevLocal/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/compiler_lock.py in _acquire_compile_lock(*args, **kwargs)
     30         def _acquire_compile_lock(*args, **kwargs):
     31             with self:
---> 32                 return func(*args, **kwargs)
     33         return _acquire_compile_lock
     34 

~/.conda/envs/Py3DevLocal/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/npyufunc/ufuncbuilder.py in build_ufunc(self)
    304         for sig in self._sigs:
    305             cres = self._cres[sig]
--> 306             dtypenums, ptr, env = self.build(cres)
    307             dtypelist.append(dtypenums)
    308             ptrlist.append(utils.longint(ptr))

~/.conda/envs/Py3DevLocal/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/npyufunc/ufuncbuilder.py in build(self, cres)
    328         info = build_gufunc_wrapper(
    329             self.py_func, cres, self.sin, self.sout,
--> 330             cache=self.cache, is_parfors=False,
    331         )
    332 

~/.conda/envs/Py3DevLocal/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/npyufunc/wrappers.py in build_gufunc_wrapper(py_func, cres, sin, sout, cache, is_parfors)
    501                else _GufuncWrapper)
    502     return wrapcls(
--> 503         py_func, cres, sin, sout, cache, is_parfors=is_parfors,
    504     ).build()
    505 

~/.conda/envs/Py3DevLocal/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/compiler_lock.py in _acquire_compile_lock(*args, **kwargs)
     30         def _acquire_compile_lock(*args, **kwargs):
     31             with self:
---> 32                 return func(*args, **kwargs)
     33         return _acquire_compile_lock
     34 

~/.conda/envs/Py3DevLocal/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/npyufunc/wrappers.py in build(self)
    454     def build(self):
    455         wrapper_name = "__gufunc__." + self.fndesc.mangled_name
--> 456         wrapperlib = self._compile_wrapper(wrapper_name)
    457         return _wrapper_info(
    458             library=wrapperlib, env=self.env, name=wrapper_name,

~/.conda/envs/Py3DevLocal/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/npyufunc/wrappers.py in _compile_wrapper(self, wrapper_name)
    445                 wrapperlib.enable_object_caching()
    446                 # Build wrapper
--> 447                 self._build_wrapper(wrapperlib, wrapper_name)
    448                 # Cache
    449                 self.cache.save_overload(self.cres.signature, wrapperlib)

~/.conda/envs/Py3DevLocal/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/npyufunc/wrappers.py in _build_wrapper(self, library, name)
    399                                            self.sin + self.sout)):
    400             ary = GUArrayArg(self.context, builder, arg_args,
--> 401                              arg_steps, i, step_offset, typ, sym, sym_dim)
    402             step_offset += len(sym)
    403             arrays.append(ary)

~/.conda/envs/Py3DevLocal/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/npyufunc/wrappers.py in __init__(self, context, builder, args, steps, i, step_offset, typ, syms, sym_dim)
    656             if syms:
    657                 raise TypeError("scalar type {0} given for non scalar "
--> 658                                 "argument #{1}".format(typ, i + 1))
    659             self._loader = _ScalarArgLoader(dtype=typ, stride=core_step)
    660 

TypeError: scalar type tuple(array(float64, 1d, A) x 2) given for non scalar argument #3
```

Comment: Although there are likely good and specific reasons behind the question, I think before moving forward it may good to make sure other easier options are not suited. For example, 1) using 2 numpy arrays (1 for the sum and 1 for the difference) or 2) a 3-dimensional numpy array (the tuple being stored in the third dimension with len = 2). I think such solutions are not only easier to implement and optimized, but in general preferred even in pure numpy.

Comment: How to return two arrays? The function can only return tuple unless we define two separate functions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Numba example, returning a tuple of 2 2-dimensional NumPy arrays.
In this case I think you could just use sum and subtraction in NumPy (if having two arrays is fine), but I'm adding here a working example with Numba. I'm applying the decorator in the following way because I find it convenient, but it is perfectly equivalent if you prefer to change back to the typical way.

```
import numpy as np

try:
    from numba import jit, prange
except ImportError:
    numba_opt = False
else:
    numba_opt = True

a = np.array([[4, 7, 9],
             [7, 1, 2]], dtype=float)
b = np.array([[5, 6, 6],
             [2, 5, 6]], dtype=float)

def numba_function(a: np.ndarray, b: np.ndarray):
    l0 = np.shape(a)[0]
    l1 = np.shape(a)[1]
    p = np.zeros_like(a)
    m = np.zeros_like(a)
    for i in range(l0):
        for j in range(l1):
            p[i, j] = a[i, j] + b[i, j]
            m[i, j] = a[i, j] - b[i, j]
    return(p, m)

if numba_opt:
    fun_rec = jit(signature_or_function='UniTuple(float64[:,:],2)(float64[:,:],float64[:,:])',
                  nopython=True, parallel=False, cache=True, fastmath=True, nogil=True)(numba_function)


p, m = fun_rec(a, b)
print(p)
print(m)
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work as intended:

```
@guvectorize([void(float64[:], float64[:], float64[:], float64[:])], '(n), (n) -> (n), (n)')
def fun(x, y, addition, subtraction):
    addition[:] = x + y
    subtraction[:] = x - y
```

For example:

```
>>> a = np.array([1., 2., 3.])
>>> b = np.array([-1., 4., 2.])
>>> fun(a, b)
(array([0., 6., 5.]), array([ 2., -2.,  1.]))
```